# Как получать письма из /var/spool/xxx себе на почту?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail

Ситуация: поднял веб-сервер на ubuntu для 3-х внутренних сайтов в сети компании. Когда захожу по ssh на него, то периодически пишет, что, мол, вам письмо. Они лежат в  /var/spool/xxx, где xxx - root и другие пользователи. 
Как автоматически пересылать эти письма к себе на рабочую почту? Видимо, к тому же надо еще что-то сделать с hostname машины, т.к. якобы все идет от домена в виде имени машины, а ведь тогда принимающий сервер может отбросить эти письма из-за DMARC, SPF и т.д? Как быть? Что делать? 
Пример присланных сообщений:

```
root@my-ubuntu-host:/home/company-site.ru# cat /var/mail/root
From root@my-ubuntu-host  Wed Aug 29 00:12:43 2018
Return-Path: <root@my-ubuntu-host>
Received: from my-ubuntu-host (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
        by my-ubuntu-host (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-10) with ESMTPS id ww43h33erge4y5
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 bits=256 verify=NOT)
        for <root@my-ubuntu-host>; Wed, 29 Aug 2018 00:12:43 +0500
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by my-ubuntu-host (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id w7SJCggO032352
        for root; Wed, 29 Aug 2018 00:12:42 +0500
Date: Wed, 29 Aug 2018 00:12:42 +0500
Message-Id: <201808281912.w7SJCggO032352@my-ubuntu-host>
From: Anacron <root@my-ubuntu-host>
To: root@my-ubuntu-host
Subject: Anacron job 'cron.weekly' on my-ubuntu-host
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-IMAPbase: 1535694118 2
Status: O
X-UID: 1

/etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common:
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

-----------------------------------------------------------------
From MAILER-DAEMON  Mon Aug 27 16:57:58 2018
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
        by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-10) id d234rgwehw455yrt;
        Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201808271157.d234rgwehw455yrt@localhost.localdomain>
To: <company-site.ru@localhost.localdomain>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="d234rgwehw455yrt.1535371078/localhost.localdomain"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--d234rgwehw455yrt.1535371078/localhost.localdomain

The original message was received at Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500
from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<owner-fio@company-site.ru>
    (reason: 553 5.3.5 system config error)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
553 5.3.5 company-site.ru. config error: mail loops back to me (MX problem?)
554 5.3.5 Local configuration error
550 5.1.1 postmaster... User unknown

--d234rgwehw455yrt.1535371078/localhost.localdomain
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; localhost.localdomain
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500

Final-Recipient: RFC822; owner-fio@company-site.ru
Action: failed
Status: 5.3.5
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 553 5.3.5 system config error
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500

--d234rgwehw455yrt.1535371078/localhost.localdomain
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <company-site.ru@localhost.localdomain>
Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
        by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-10) with ESMTPS id w7RBvw6r013350
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 bits=256 verify=NOT)
        for <owner-fio@company-site.ru>; Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id w7RBvwts013349
        for owner-fio@company-site.ru; Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 16:57:58 +0500
From: company-site.ru <company-site.ru@localhost.localdomain>
Message-Id: <201808271157.w7RBvwts013349@localhost.localdomain>

--d234rgwehw455yrt.1535371078/localhost.localdomain--
```

Comment: **0**. Я думал, что сендмэйлом уже никто не пользуется. **1**. В файле `/etc/aliases`  указать, что почта для пользователя `root` должна быть направлена на адрес `aaa@company.com`: `root:   aaa@company.com`, и выполнить команду `newaliases`; либо в хоум папке рута создать файл `.forward` в который прописать адрес `aaa@company.com`. **2**. Но основная ваша задача будет в том, чтобы объяснить почтовику, как посылать письма наружу. Я же правильно понял, что сендмэйл находится в офисе, а ваш корпоративный почтовик за пределами? Я бы использовал опцию `SMART_HOST` + необходимые сетевые настройки.

Comment: @de_frag, да, веб-сервер и почтовик разнесены. Меня ставят в тупик настройки имен машин, которые hostname, и которые в hosts нужно прописать. Не могу нагуглить именно свою проблему.

Comment: А вы начните с того, дойдут ли с этого сервера (который веб) письма на почтовый сервер (который корпоративный). Т.е. доходят ли они физически хоть в каком-нибудь виде. Возможно вам сначала надо победить все сетевые доступы, прежде чем заниматься тюнингом почтовика веб-сервера.

Comment: @de_frag, поставил exim4, настроил и все разрешилось. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

вопрос содержит в себе много вложенных вопросов (их лучше задать отдельно), каждый из которых и сам по себе весьма обширен. потому привожу лишь краткий общий план действий.

1. для того, чтобы отправляемые с вашего компьютера сообщения могли покинуть его пределы и быть доставлеными «во внешний мир», вам надо установить и настроить хоть какой-нибудь [*mta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) (как правило, его средствами можно и подменять отправителя).
2. чтобы сообщения, адресованные локальному пользователю (например, `root`), отправлялись какому-то другому пользователю (например, `ja@mojdomen.ru`), надо добавить в конце файла `/etc/aliases` строку вида:

   ```
   root: ja@mojdomen.ru
   ```

   в зависимости от установленного *mta* это изменение может быть «подхвачено на лету», либо требовать выполнения ещё какой-нибудь дополнительной программы (что-нибудь вроде `newaliases`) — уточняйте в документации к вашему *mta*.
3. чтобы переслать сообщения, аккумулированные в локальном [mbox-файле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) (например, `/var/mail/пользователь`), какому-нибудь другому пользователю, можно воспользоваться программой *formail* (из пакета `procmail`). см. `man formail` (локально или [онлайн](https://linux.die.net/man/1/formail)) и, например, [вот эту инструкцию](http://giantdorks.org/alain/resend-mail-thats-locally-stored-in-a-mbox-format-on-a-linux-box-to-a-working-email-address/).

Comment: поставил exim4, настроил и все разрешилось. Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers